# migrate-naming-strategy not working in Pimcore 6.9

Tags: symfony, pimcore

I have a Pimcore instance v 6.9. with editables naming strategy set to legacy:

```yaml
pimcore:
    documents:
        editables:
            naming_strategy: legacy
```

I would like to upgrade to 10.x for which the requirement is to use nested naming strategy, but when running console command `bin/console pimcore:documents:migrate-naming-strategy` [to convert naming strategy to nested](https://pimcore.com/docs/pimcore/6.9/Development_Documentation/Documents/Editable_Naming_Strategies.html) there is an error:

> The migration strategy "render" does not exist

I looked into code and the problem seems to be that command can't fetch requested service from Symfony container:

```php
$strategyId = 'pimcore.document.tag.naming.migration.strategy.render';
$container->has($strategyId)
```

I have tried making making service `pimcore.document.tag.naming.migration.strategy.render` in Symfony container as public, but this didn't solve the issue.

I have also tried to downgrade Pimcore to lover versions but the result is same.

How can I mitigate this issue?

Comment: It seems that this command is not working in version 6.9 so I would suggest to anyone still on version 5.x to migrate naming strategy from legacy to nested before upgrading to 6.x

Comment: I am stuck at the same point. Were you able to run the migration in the end? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If I remember correctly, what I did was saving my current work from upgrade process, then going back to version 5 and running the command and then re-applying other upgrade steps again. It was easier than making the command work on 6.9

Comment: Thank you @KoviNET. I don't think I will be able to take that path. If I find another solution I will post it here :) Thank you very much again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For us this worked at Pimcore 6.9.6 by adding the following lines from https://github.com/pimcore/pimcore/blob/v5.8.9/bundles/CoreBundle/Resources/config/documents.yml to our services.yml below services:

```
#
# DOCUMENT TAG MIGRATION
#

pimcore.document.tag.naming.migration.strategy.analyze:
    public: true
    class: Pimcore\Document\Tag\NamingStrategy\Migration\AnalyzeMigrationStrategy
    arguments:
        $db: '@database_connection'

pimcore.document.tag.naming.migration.strategy.render:
    public: true
    class: Pimcore\Document\Tag\NamingStrategy\Migration\RenderMigrationStrategy

# the used naming strategy will be aliased to "pimcore.document.tag.naming.strategy" by the extension based on
# the pimcore.documents.editables.naming_strategy config value
Pimcore\Document\Tag\NamingStrategy\NamingStrategyInterface: '@pimcore.document.tag.naming.strategy'

pimcore.document.tag.naming.strategy.legacy:
    public: true
    class: Pimcore\Document\Tag\NamingStrategy\LegacyNamingStrategy

pimcore.document.tag.naming.strategy.nested:
    public: true
    class: Pimcore\Document\Tag\NamingStrategy\NestedNamingStrategy
```